# Why is there a need to restore the policies when creating an alert policy in Cloud Monitoring API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

There is a concept I don't really understand when looking at the sample code for Cloud Monitoring API (v3).

In all the [code examples for creating an alert policy](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-create-policy) there is code that "restores" the policies first before making a new one. Also the function names for the examples isn't "creating" a policy, it's "restoring". I don't quite understand why this is needed. Is there a reason for why policies need to be "restored"? What does "restored" mean?

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-api#api-create-policy

Here is one of the examples (Java)

```
private static void restoreRevisedPolicies(
String projectId, boolean isSameProject, List<AlertPolicy> policies) throws IOException {
  try (AlertPolicyServiceClient client = AlertPolicyServiceClient.create()) {
    for (AlertPolicy policy : policies) {
      if (!isSameProject) {
        policy = client.createAlertPolicy(ProjectName.of(projectId), policy);
      } else {
        try {
          client.updateAlertPolicy(null, policy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          policy =
              client.createAlertPolicy(
                  ProjectName.of(projectId), policy.toBuilder().clearName().build());
        }
      }
      System.out.println(String.format("Restored %s", policy.getName()));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Those are valid examples of using the "create" API call, and  the "restore" function is there because the same example code is used also in the "Backup and restore" section, but this makes it no less of a valid example.